# Средний и наиболее близкий цвета

Tags: java, графика, rgb

Суть в том, чтобы рассчитать средний цвет изображения, а также реализовать поиск самого похожего цвета.
У меня есть грубые идеи вроде расчета средних значений для R, G и B компонент для вычисления среднего цвета, и нахождение минимальной суммы разностей этих компонент для подбора похожего цвета.
Есть идеи получше?

Comment: Для нахождения среднего цвета, наверное, будет достаточно вычислить средние значения компонентов. А что такое "наиболее близкий" цвет? Близкий к чему?

Comment: поисмотритесь к палитре hsl, в ней легче будет, имхо

Comment: Наиболее близкий к заданному (массив цветов, какой элемент массива ближайший к нему?) . Можно конкретнее про hsl?

Comment: А что значит "ближайший"?

Comment: @Krutoy4el не будет наиболее близким цвет у которого один из компонент сместится на одну позицию?

Comment: Нет, есть массив цветов. Для цвета которого нет в массиве, надо найти наиболее подходящий из массива

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно взять дистанцию:

```java
public static BigDecimal distance(Color from, Color to) {
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.sqrt(
            Math.pow(from.getRed() - to.getRed(), 2)
            + Math.pow(from.getGreen() - to.getGreen(), 2)
            + Math.pow(from.getBlue() - to.getBlue(), 2)
    ));
}
```

И далее воспользоваться стримами. Вот пример:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Color testColor = Color.GRAY;
    List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    colors.add(Color.BLUE);
    colors.add(Color.ORANGE);
    colors.add(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    colors.add(Color.YELLOW);
    Color result = colors.stream().reduce((c1, c2) ->
            distance(c1, testColor).compareTo(distance(c2, testColor)) < 0 ? c1 : c2
    ).get();
    System.out.println(colors);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Вывод:

```
[java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=200,b=0], java.awt.Color[r=192,g=192,b=192], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=0]]
java.awt.Color[r=192,g=192,b=192]
```

Видно, что серый наиболее близок к светлосерому из имеющихся цветов.

Comment: Гениально, а главное так просто! Всего-лишь трехмерное пространство.

Answer (score 0):

Советую Вам посмотреть готовые библиотеки, например, [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/4.4.0). К сожалению, не могу накидать решение полностью, но ниже код нахождения среднего цвета:

```
import nu.pattern.OpenCV;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        OpenCV.loadShared();
        Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread("/path/to/image");
        Scalar scalar = Core.mean(img);
        System.out.println(scalar);
    }

}
```

Тестовое изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

```
[58.11971896196495, 69.30190753987546, 91.63179155959905, 0.0]
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду экспериментировать)